# Where Jboss7.1 take war application to deploy

Tags: jboss7.x

I've deployed the jboss-as-helloworld-errai application in my standalone jboss7.1 instance, and I deleted it later ( in the */standalone/deployments folder). But every time I restart my server it redeploys that application.
Is there another place where jboss reads the application to deploy?
Best regard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you delete the file while the server was running?

Probably, JBoss still finds a deployment information in one your `/standalone/configuration/standalone*.xml` files (at the end of the file). JBoss unpacks its deployments in one of the `/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp*` folders. As long as it finds a deployment in your configuration file, it will start the application.

The deployment binaries are located under the `standalone/data/content`. These would also need to be deleted. The best solution is to properly undeploy the application via CLI, the maven plug-in or the web console.

Comment: You don't need the XML or to be deleting fron the `/standalone/data/content` folder. There is some other behaviour at play here, and likely user issues with the marker file.

Answer (score 2):

This does not sound like expected behaviour. Can you please confirm the steps that you are taking when using the deployment folder? For example:

### Deploy

1. Copy application file to `/standalone/deployments` folder
2. Deployment Scanner creates a `.dodeploy` marker file
3. Deployment Scanner picks up application and creates a `.deployed` marker file
4. Application confirmed as deployed (checking the Management Console to confirm)

### Undeploy

1. Application deleted from `/standalone/deployments` folder
2. Delete application (or) delete `.deployed` marker file
3. Deployment scanner undeploys the application and creates `.undeployed` marker file
4. Confirm application removed in console
5. Restart server
6. Confirmed removal is persistent

The `README.txt` file in the `deployments` folder shows the simple undeployment workflow in one easy step in the command line.

1. `rm $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war.deployed`

### Documentation

You can read more about the deployment scanner in the official docs. There's a topic about the scanner marker files, as well as a parent topic about the scanner and deployments in general. If you are finding issues with the scanner, it's a bug. You might like to test the expected behaviour, and also try the Management Console.

- [Red Hat Docs - Reference for Deployment Scanner Marker Files](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Beta_Documentation/Reference_for_Deployment_Scanner_Marker_Files.html)
- [Red Hat Docs - About Application Deployment](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Beta_Documentation/Deploy_Applications.html)

### Potential Issues

- Don't confuse the Deployment Scanner subsystem (which watches the Deployments folder for the Standalone server instance) with the Management Console or Management CLI deployments process. You might be better off using one of the Management tools instead of the hot deployment capability to allow for more control over the state and presence of your application.